# How to retrieve specific index value from web_reg_save_param arrray

Tags: c, loadrunner

I am using the web param function to retreive certain values. I want to get the value of a specific index from the array item and store it in a parameter to be used in a web_link call.

```
char * tempVal;
web_reg_save_param("dynArray","LB=/EmployeeProfile/","RB=\">","ORD=ALL",LAST);
tempVal = "{dynArray_2}";
```

There is no error for the above statements but when accessing tempVal it is giving error

```
vuser_init.c(143): web_link("emp") started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
vuser_init.c(143): Warning: The string 'tempVal' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
vuser_init.c(143): Error -27995: Requested link ("Text={tempVal}") not found    [MsgId: MERR-27995]
```

Comment: This example is for total count, i am looking to access specific index and store in a parameter. And also the random index option is not my requirement.

Comment: You seem to misuse LoadRunner parameterization. The `tempVal` local variable is not automatically converted into a parameter. Call `lr_save_string(tempVal, "tempVal")` to do this. Then you will be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem which is C language based.  You cannot simply equate two items as you have done.

take a look at the strcpy() function combined with lr_eval_string()

```
strcpy (destination_C_variable, lr_eval_string( "{LoadRunner_source_variable}" ) );
```

Comment: Using    strcpy (tempVal, lr_eval_string( "{dynArray_2}" ) ); Getting errors.......vuser_init.c(134): Warning: The string 'dynArray_2' with parameter delimiters is not a parameter.
vuser_init.c(134): Error: C interpreter run time error: vuser_init.c (134):  Error -- memory violation : Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION received.

Comment: Looking at your original example above, you will not have any values until after the following page is loaded.  web_reg_() functions are service functions.  They act as a colander and are seeded once the following web_() function completes and returns a page.   So, running this immediately after a web_reg_save_...() function before the following page return will result in an error.  This is an expected error in such a case as the variable does not yet exist and is not populated with a value